# PostgreSQL function round and JPA/Hibernate

Tags: postgresql, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have a query which is executed from java application like this:

```
Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery(hql);
```

The query looks like this:

```
String hql = "select * from table a where round(column1, 3) = round(parameter, 3)";
```

Here `column1` is of type `Double`. The value it holds is like `143.02856666`. I need to retain the value as it is, but for some business logic just need to round and compare.

The initial database configured was H2 and this worked fine. Now the database has been changed to Postgres and this query now errors out.

> ERROR: function round(double precision, integer) does not exist   Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might
>   need to add explicit type casts.

The `round()` function in Postgres takes a numeric datatype and needs a cast.

The below query works fine if executed directly in Postgres console.

```
select * from table a where round(cast(column1 as numeric), 3) = round(cast(parameter as numeric), 3);
```

The same from java application errors out.

> **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: Could not resolve requested type for CAST : numeric**

Also tried `Query query = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(hql);`
This results in a new error.

> **org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper  - ERROR: syntax error at or near "where"**

If I debug, this errors out when the below line is executed.

```
List resultList = query.getResultList();
```

How do I rewrite the query so that it works against Postgres ?

Comment: Is `parameter` an actual parameter and no column in your table? If so, how would your query work if the query-string never got manipulated? Plus i just tested a nativeQuery with Eclipselink and Postgres and it works. And I advice you to always cut the question to it's essentials and providing the table-definition for a question like this...

Comment: Thanks, my bad will take care. The parameter will be passed in to the method in which this query executes. Its like :parmeter and will be passed in using .setParameter("parameter", parameterValue);

Comment: I have fixed this by casting to big_decimal which maps to numeric. round(cast(column1 as numeric), 3) to round(cast(column1 as big_decimal), 3). Enabling show_sql displays this query as round(cast(column1 as numeric(19,2), 3) in console. Any pointer if this can be written in a way so that it translates numeric(19,2) to numeric(19,6) as this will give me more accurate results.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing with `Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery(hql);` is calling a `jpql`-query, which does not support all db-functions like `round(v numeric, s integer)`.

Two Suggestions:

1. Use `BETWEEN` and maintain jpql-mapping
2. Write a NativeQuery -> `Query query = em.createNativeQuery(queryString);`

Your `queryString` just has to be altered by your parameters.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion, I did tried using createNativeQuery, but didn't work. The issue was with mapping data type. Please see my comment above.