# Could not resolve requested type for CAST : bigint

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I have a case where my hibernate entity class has string field and postgres has bigint type for the same field. when I tried to execute query against the field it threw 'incompatible types'. when I tried casting the entity field to bigint(cast(fieldname as bigint)),I am getting below exception. 'Could not resolve requested type for CAST : numeric'.. Can someone help here ?

Here is the code snippet.

```
@Entity
@Table(name=“CB_MSG”)
public class Chargeback {
....
....

@Column(name="CHRGBK_MSG_SEQ_NUM")
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="CB_ID", sequenceName="OB_CHRGBK_MSG_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator="CB_ID", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
@Column(name="CB_REF_NUM”)
    public String getChargeBackReferenceNo() {
        return chargeBackReferenceNo;
    }
.....
}
```

This property is defined as bigint in postgres table and I am trying to query as below.

```
@Override
    public Chargeback getChargebackById(String chargebackRefNum) {
       String finalQuery= "FROM Chargeback CB WHERE cast(CB.chargeBackReferenceNo as bigint) = “ + chargebackRefNum;

        Chargeback result = (Chargeback) entityManager.createQuery(finalQuery).getSingleResult();
        return result;
    }
```

PS: I don't have a control over database schema and can't make any changes in that.

Comment: Can we see code?

Comment: "Has bigint for the same column" sounds as if you mistakenly defined the column as `oid` (aka "large object"). Your obfuscation layer ("Hibernate") is known to now work correctly with some Postgres and e.g. the `@Lob` annotation. But to know if that is the case you need to **[edit]** your code and provide the Java code with the annotated entity. Do **not** post code in comments, [edit] your question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37759993/postgresql-function-round-and-jpa-hibernate

This might help in solve the issue